# ERROR: Traceback: in <module> TypeError: mood_today() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mood'

Tags: python

I recently started getting into python and was using Edabit.com to do some challenges. I was doing a challenge that said:

"Create a function that takes in a current mood and return a sentence in the following format: 'Today, I am feeling {mood}'. However, if no argument is passed, return 'Today, I am feeling neutral'."

For some reason I keep getting `ERROR: Traceback:    in <module> TypeError: mood_today() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mood'` in my code. The only test which my code didn't pass was when no input was given so I'm guessing that the cause of my problem is the second line of my function.

```
 def mood_today(mood):
        if mood==None:
            return "Today, I am feeling neutral"
        else:
            return "Today, I am feeling " + mood
```

after lots of trial and error, I gave up and looked at a solution which is the following.

```
def mood_today(mood = 'neutral'):
    return 'Today, I am feeling '+ mood
```

Why do they have "mood='neutral'" inside the parenthesis when defining the function? Is it that if there's no input that the function will default mood to 'neutral'? Could someone please explain? Also thank you to all future answers!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Try reading https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-default-arguments-in-python

Answer (score 1):

```
mood = input("Enter your mood - ")
def mood_today(mood):
         if len(mood) < 1 :
             return "Today, I am feeling neutral"
         else:
             return "Today, I am feeling " + mood
 print(mood_today(mood))
```

This code will print "Today ,I am feeling neutral" when no input is passed . If there is input then this will print "Today, I am feeling "+ mood.
May this helps you.